# ACF Repeater Field Question

Tags: plugins, php

I am using Advanced Custom Fields to make 3 service boxes.

I want to use the repeater field to loop three divs that are containing the six paragraphs and images. The problem having is that is looping right way but content inside class name services is looping individually

I want this paragraphs and images to display in twos inside the 3 divs.

```
<div class''services>
   <div class="box-service">Content Go Here</div>
   <div class="box-service">Content Go Here</div>
</div>

<div class''services>
   <div class="box-service">Content Go Here</div>
   <div class="box-service">Content Go Here</div>
</div>

<div class''services>
   <div class="box-service">Content Go Here</div>
   <div class="box-service">Content Go Here</div>
</div>
```

Wordpress Code

```
<section class="services cf">
    <div class="wrapper">  
        <?php if( have_rows('services_sections') ): ?>


        <?php while( have_rows('services_sections') ): the_row(); 

            // vars
            $image = get_sub_field('services_icon');
            $title = get_sub_field('service_title');
            $description = get_sub_field('services_description');

        ?>

        <div class="service">
            <div class="box-service">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <div class="right-word">
                        <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</section>


// -------- Services Styles --------- //

.services {
    clear: both;

    .line {
        border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    }

    .service {
        background-color: $offwhitecolor;
        width: 31%;
        float: left;
        margin: -5rem 1%  1%;
        text-align: left;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px rgba(38,40,44,0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px rgba(38,40,44,0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px rgba(38,40,44,0.2);

        .box-service {
            padding: 1rem 7.5% 1rem;


            h3 {
                font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                font-size: 1.0rem;
                font-weight: 700;
            }

            p {
                font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                font-size: 1.0037500100376rem;
                font-weight: 300;
            }

            .right-word {
                padding-left: 30px;
            }

            .left-icon {
                margin: 35px -5px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Brandon, WPSE does not handle questions concerning third party plugins and themes. Answering these questions requires detailed knowledge of the workings of these codebases. Please use the [Advanced Custom Fields Support Forum](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/) for help on this issue. [More on what topics *can* be asked about cab be read here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sometimes i get this error when i'm not in a loop.  Are you inside a loop?   if not you may need to add: the post id (which would have to be defined as well something like this for each variable.:
    $image = get_sub_field('services_icon', $postid);  Need more info to give a real answer.

Comment: @rudtek Hello not an error might have to explain better do you have a skype or like google hangout so I screen share

Comment: can you post the whole code you have already for the template page and I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to create a **sub repeater field**(lets call `box_service`) inside the **repeater field** `services_sections`. Then create the sub fields (`services_icon, service_title, services_description` )inside `box_service` repeater field. (please check attachment)[image])

then use below code :

```
<section class="services cf">
<div class="wrapper">  
    <?php if( have_rows('services_sections') ): 

     while( have_rows('services_sections') ): the_row(); ?>

     <div class="service">

    <?php if( have_rows('box_service') ): 


    while( have_rows('box_service') ): the_row(); 

        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('services_icon');
        $title = get_sub_field('service_title');
        $description = get_sub_field('services_description');

    ?>


        <div class="box-service">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="right-word">
                    <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
                </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</div>
```